# Any way to have Flask session store in local storage instead of a cookie?

Tags: flask

I would rather store the session information for a website on local Storage instead of a cookie.  So as flask would not send a cookie.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I can't flask
But you can distinguish the client through client IP and UA or other forms, and conserve the relevant information of the client.

Another way is to return token like a client, and each subsequent client request needs to contain (via get or post) the token.

But these two methods are not completely reliable.